# CSS Full Hexadecimal Value for Colour When in Two Characters?

Tags: css

I have accidentally typed following color

```
"#ff"
```

[image]

in CSS and gives me an nice color, now i want to get the full color in Hexadecimal value,

When i tried following it still gave me the wrong colour.

```
"#ffffff" 
"#ff0000"
"#fff"
```

any idea ?

Comment: Could you maybe provide snapshot of color or describe it? Different clients are going to interpret that invalid value in different ways, so getting actual color loaded will depend on client.

Comment: um.. is that large black square a picture of the color you are wanting, um.. black? (#000000)

Answer (score 0):

I think the full hex value you're looking for could be #0000ff.

I use a Chrome extension called ColorZilla. It has a Color Picker tool which I used to search for #ff and it gave me the full hex code.

Comment: attached the colour screenshot